# control state of ng-show in a loop of a particular element

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, control-state

I'm dynamically generating a list of actions within my form. Example, save, approve, reject. When you click one of those actions, I'd like a spinner to appear within that button until I get a successful response from the server.

I have the following code.

buttons

```
<button type="submit" value="{{e.label}}" ng-click="getCtrlScope().formData.requestAction=e.action;" class="btn {{e.btnStyle}}"  ng-repeat="e in buttonActions">
    <span ng-show="saveState == 'save'"> {{e.label}} </span> 
    <span ng-show="saveState == 'loading'"> {{e.label}} 
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </span> 
    <span ng-show="saveState == 'completed'"> {{e.label}} 
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

js

```
$scope.saveState = 'save' ;

$scope.save = function() {      
    $scope.saveState = 'loading'

    $http.post('../reviewRequest.json', $scope.formData).then(
        function(response) {    
            $scope.saveState = 'save'
        }, function(response) {
    });
};
```

As you can probable see, when you click an action all my buttons will start spinning. How do I limit the spin to a single button?

Comment: the "loading" state must be a button property not a $scope one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good practic, as mentioned by @fantarama, you should use a property inside the element, not the $scope.

Anyway, if you don't mind to, you could store the element you clicked on with your `ng-click call`

```
ng-click="getCtrlScope(e)..."
```

Store that element in some variable:

```
function getCtrlScope(element) {
    $scope.clickedElement = element;
    ...
}
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<span ng-show="saveState == 'save' && e !== clickedElement"> {{e.label}} </span> 
<span ng-show="saveState == 'loading' && e === clickedElement"> {{e.label}} 
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</span>
<span ng-show="saveState == 'completed' && e === clickedElement"> {{e.label}}
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</span>
```

**EDIT**

Assuming your POST call is located in the getCtrlScope, you could do something like:

- As mentionned before, add the element in the function call that you'll pass to the save function
- Store the state in the element itself (don't forget to initialize it)
- Update the `ng-show` conditions

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" value="{{e.label}}" ng-click="getCtrlScope(e).formData.requestAction=e.action;" class="btn {{e.btnStyle}}" ng-repeat="e in buttonActions">
    <span ng-show="e.saveState == 'save'"> {{e.label}} </span> 
    <span ng-show="e.saveState == 'loading'"> {{e.label}} 
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="e.saveState == 'completed'"> {{e.label}}
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.save = function(element) {      
    element.saveState = 'loading'

    $http.post('../reviewRequest.json', $scope.formData).then(
        function(response) {    
            element.saveState = 'save'
        }, function(response) {
    });
};
```

Based on your Plunker, I modified it a little. As you can see, the state of each button changes in an independant way as you click on them.

See the result [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VAbADXEwCYCdxgZNh2YK?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, everything makes sense except the saveState piece, would I continue doing what I'm doing now in addition to the clickedElement or is that bad practice?

Comment: @CodeJunkie I've updated my answer with some indications to use the good practice. Hope this will help.

Comment: I still seem to be having some issues, so I built a little plunker demo. Perhaps you could help me to complete the missing pieces. http://plnkr.co/edit/RxElp0gfgVSQcZHOxWPj?p=preview

Comment: @CodeJunkie I've brought some modifications to your Plunker and it seems to be working now. See my edit :)

Comment: Could you provide a link to it, I'm not seeing our edits. I appreciate our help. I'm slowly catching on to angular.

Comment: nvm, stackoverflow wasn't showing your link, I found it.

Comment: It would have been cool not to have to put the savestate in my object due to the fact the object is generated from the backend, but all in all it works. Thank you.